# Which is better: Include or src in calling a script?

Tags: javascript, php, include, require, src

what's good coding practice should be?

**Code1**

```
<script src="js/sample.js"></script>
```

or

Code2

```
<script>

    <?php include('js/sample.js'); ?>

</script>
```

Comment: Depends on the context. Loading externally is one more network request, but that request can be cached.

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="js/sample.js"></script>` Is faster and more reliable.  Loading via PHP can be definetely slower.  Especially when there are multiple other PHP requests.

Comment: *can be definitely* - does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

`<script src="js/sample.js"></script>` is better. Javascript will be loaded and save in client computer as cache. So it  will call code from cache in client computer. But PHP code will load code from server that makes it slower and your server will work harder.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="js/sample.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script> 
it is the correct syntax. W3C recommend this is a standard syntax for linking JavaScript file.
fast loading JavaScript file. and SEO optimization you required to define type of script.
```